# Force rsconnect::deployApp() to fail to test 'on.failure'

Tags: r, shiny, rsconnect

I have a `shiny` application which updates each night via `rsconnect::deployApp` using a batch file and scheduled task.  This process is currently functioning as intended, but currently the only way to confirm the success of the entire procedure is to visit the app and check if the timestamp is updated.

`?deployApp` shows an `on.failure` option which will call a function if the deployment fails.  I have ideas of how to use this to send a notification if the deploy fails but I haven't been able to test it because I can't actually make the `deployApp` function fail.

I have tried placing errors in the `UI` but the app successfully deploys, despite being non-functional in the viewer and on shinyapps.io.

Is there a way to force the `deployApp` function to fail so I am able to test the `on.failure` function I am creating?

Here's a small shiny app borrowed from [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/single-file-shiny-app.html) if needed.

```
# Global variables can go here
n <- 200


# Define the UI
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', n),
  plotOutput('plot')
)


# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(runif(input$n))
  })
}

# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Currently running R v. 4.0.2; rsconnect 0.8.16, shiny 1.5.0

Edit: I tried sneaking a `q()` into the app. It for sure breaks the app but doesn't interfere with `deployApp`. The search continues!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the `on.failure` fires when there is an error in the, well, deployment. From that perspective, errors in the code (`stop` or even `q`) trigger `on.failure` only when it tampers with the *deployment*. Since there is no apparent check of the *code* itself in `deployApp` it probably won't work like this.

Looking at the underlying `rsconnect:::openURL` (where the `on.failure` argument is used), we see that `on.failure` is used in 2 conditions:

```r
if (!is.null(client$configureApplication)) {
    config <- client$configureApplication(application$id)
    url <- config$config_url
    if (!deploymentSucceeded && validURL(config$logs_url)) {
        url <- config$logs_url
    }
    if (validURL(url)) {
        if (deploymentSucceeded) {
            showURL(url)
        }
        else if (is.function(on.failure)) {
            on.failure(url) ## here
        }
    }
}
else if (deploymentSucceeded) {
    showURL(application$url)
}
else if (is.function(on.failure)) {
    on.failure(NULL) ## and here
}
```

So what I would do to test, is to `debug(rsconnect:::openURL)` and when the browser opens, I would simply set `client$configureApplication <- NULL;deploymentSucceeded <- FALSE` and continue with the code.

However, looking at the code, we see all what will happen is that, `on.failure` is called. Thus, calling `on.failure` directly will have the same effect.

Comment: So if `on.failure` is my created function, simply testing the function should suffice?    As far as the `debug(rsconnect:::openURL)` and setting the values within, would I include those into my shiny app and then try to deploy?  Apologies, I'm inexperienced with debugging.

Comment: Yes. And no, you run `debug(rsconnect:::openURL)` in the R command shell and then you run the deploy function. Once the function calls `openURL` you will see  that in the R shell you can now run each line of `openURL` one by one and after each line, R stops and let you run whatever R code you wish and you want to change the value of two variables. Cf https://adv-r.hadley.nz/debugging.html